# Single header which includes other headers

Tags: c++, c

Recently, I encountered such approach of managing headers. Could not find much info on its problems on internet, so decided to ask here.

Imagine you have a program where you have `main.c`, and also other sources and headers like: `person.c, person.h, settings.c, settings.h, maindialog.c, maindialog.h, othersource.c, othersource.h`

sometimes `settings.c` might need `person.c` and main `maindialog.c`.

Sometimes some other source might need to include other source files.
Typically one would do inside `settings.c`:

```
//settings.c
#include "person.h"
#include "maindialog.h"
```

But, I encountered approach where one has `global.h` and inside it:

```
//global.h
//all headers we need
#include "person.h"
#include "maindialog.h"
#include "settings.h"
#include "otherdialog.h"
```

Now, from each other source file you only have to include `"global.h"`
and you are done, you get functionality from respective source files.
Does this approach with one `global.h` header has some real problems?

Comment: A common way of dealing with this is to wrap each header file in  `#ifndef xxxx / #define xxxx / #endif`, so that even if it does get included twice the second time it will be ignored.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Hi Jonathan, yes that is include guards, I usually have include guards even in case with global header approach (in each header). But further I found using such global header simpler .... (since you include only one header)

Comment: The main problem is that it *maximizes* dependencies. You should be trying to *minimize* those.

Comment: @juanchopanza: ok about dependencies, but unless it had some real problems, I usually found this approach easier to use ...

Comment: or you could use #pragma once

Comment: It would get thrown out of any code review I was in!

Comment: @juanchopanza: so you suggest in each source I include only those headers that I need? (and just use include guards), and done?

Comment: Yes, include only the ones you need, and all the ones you need. Do not rely on some header including others.

Comment: @juanchopanza: ok so I see you suggestion and + include guards in all header files is another alternative?

Comment: Use forward declarations as much as possible. Usually a good idea that you can compile the header with as few `#include`s as possible.

Comment: No, include guards for headers is a must. Otherwise you will run into multiple declaration errors and all kinds of troubles. A header needs to have include guards.

Comment: @juanchopanza - in general headers should have guards, but this isn't absolutely always true -- there are some techniques that rely on including a header multiple times with different `#defines` that would break with header guards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to please both pedantic purists and lazy minimalists. If all sub-headers are done the correct way there is no functional harm including them via `global.h`, only possible compile time increase.

Subheader would be somewhat like

```
#ifndef unique_token
#define unique_token
#pragma once

// the useful payload

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are common headers that all the source files need, (like config.h) you can do so. (but use it like precompiled headers...)

But by including unnecessary headers, you actually increasing the compilation time. so if you have a really big project and for every source file you including all the headers, compilation time can be very long...

I suggest not include headers unless you must.
Even if you use type, but only for pointer or reference (especially in headers), prefer to use fwd declaration instead of include.